# To change window properties by event handler

Tags: wpf

I need to change properties (ex background color) of **Window** based on Event handler.
we can easily do this to any controls inside window by writing it in windows.Resources as shown below.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.Window1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication8"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
            >
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
                <EventSetter Event="SizeChanged" Handler="OnbuttonLoaded"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button x:Name="Button1" Width="100" Height="20"/>
            <Button Width="100" Height="20"/>
            <Button Width="100" Height="20"/>
            <Button Width="100" Height="20"/>
            <Button Width="100" Height="20"/>
        </StackPanel>
</window>
```

xaml.cs is as follows

```
 private void OnbuttonLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button1.Background = Brushes.Red;
        }
```

But when I have to change **background color of window** itself when it's SizeChanged. what can i do???
Please do help.... Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And why not to use Window Style property?

```
<Window.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <EventSetter Event="SizeChanged" Handler="EventSetter_OnHandler"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Style>
```

If you need some global solution, put it in App Resources.